# How to load dynamic data tables in ajax with pagination?

Tags: codeigniter

How do load dynamic data tables ajax with pagination in Codeigniter. 100 records in db 1st loading in 10 records next on click again load next 10 records from database.

Comment: Please share, what you have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the good example for pagination using codeigniter

http://codesamplez.com/development/codeigniter-pagination-tutorial

Comment: Thanking, but i want without page loading and not value passed in uri segment.